# Sub choices to .addChoices in slashcommand

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here the beggining of my module.export for a slash command

```
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("environnement")
    .setDescription("Donne la carte, la météo et le store")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("category")
        .setDescription("The gif category")
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices(
          { name: "Carte", value: "carte" },
          { name: "Météo", value: "meteo" },
          { name: "Store", value: "store" }
        )
    ),
```

I would like to add sub choices to the .addChoices meaning that when we enter /environment we get "category" which lead to the three choices. From there I would like various possibilities in the store.

Do you know if it is possible ?

I am using last version of discord.js (14.1.2)
Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In fact, the code you have there should be working. Was there a problem with it?

Comment: No there is no problem with this code :). It works perfectly.
From /environement I got category which have the three choices Carte, Meteo and Store. 
But now from "Store" I would like to have the possibility to have 2 "sub"-choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible (yet?). 
If you really want this to happen you can use subcommands (https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#subcommands), but be aware of the Discord API Limit of 25 subcommands per command.